# Seems like Hibernate exceeds connection limit

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

Can anybody help me solve this situation?
I have a Tomcat and simple JSF Application: https://github.com/gooamoko/jsfbilling/.
When I run application on Tomcat, it runs normally, but after several requests (for example 10 quick refresh page) raise the exception `can't open connection`.
I think, it's normal, but where is the mistake?

In the configuration file hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/netstat</property>
        <property name="connection.username">netstat</property>
        <property name="connection.password">netstat</property>

        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- configuration pool via c3p0 -->
        <property name="c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_statements">200</property>
        <property name="c3p0.timeout">600</property> <!-- seconds -->

        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <!-- Mapping classes -->
        <mapping class="ru.gooamoko.model.Group" />
        <mapping class="ru.gooamoko.model.Host" />
        <mapping class="ru.gooamoko.model.Traffic" />
        <mapping class="ru.gooamoko.model.DailyTraffic" />

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

or in the Java classess

```
package ru.gooamoko.dao;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateProvider {
    private static SessionFactory factory;
    private static ServiceRegistry registry;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
                configuration.getProperties()).build();
        factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry);
        return factory;
    }

}


package ru.gooamoko.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

public class GenericDao {

    private SessionFactory factory;
    protected Session session;

    protected void begin() {
        session = factory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
    }

    protected void commit() {
        if (session.isOpen()) {
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }

    protected void rollback() {
        if (session.isOpen()) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    }

    public GenericDao() {
        this.factory = HibernateProvider.getSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

In the tomcat log I see this

```
27-Aug-2014 15:06:24.559 WARNING [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge12w9467h4hm1tfa5tj|3b40a97d]-HelperThread-#2] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.forceKillAcquires Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@4df5a3a4 is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
27-Aug-2014 15:06:24.563 WARNING [C3P0PooledConnectionPoolManager[identityToken->1hge12w9467h4hm1tfa5tj|3b40a97d]-HelperThread-#2] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@628977a2 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ?????: ?????????? ????? ??????????? ??????????????? ??? ??????????? ????????????????? (?? ??? ??????????)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:572)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:177)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:146)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:195)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:184)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
```

How and where should I correct close open connections?

Thanks for wasting your time for me.

Comment: May be because you don't close connections to database? Any way you should use connection pool.

Comment: Please don't link to code. Include the most relevant parts of it directly in your question. If you'll delete that github project or the page content gets changed in the future, that links will not be helpful to other readers.

Comment: @BackSlash Ok. I'll update post.

Comment: @Andremoniy Can you give me simple example where and how can I close connection? And where can I read about using connection pools?

Comment: Post the full exception stacktrace please. "Cannot open connection" is a result, not the actual problem. Also note that it may full well be related to how the database server is configured.

Answer (score 0):

I've read Hibernate documentation and found example of `HibernateUtil` class.
After comparing with my `HibernateProvider` I found, that seems like in my `HibernateProvider` Factory was build every call of `getSessionFactory()`. New version of `HibernateProvider` is

```
package ru.gooamoko.dao;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateProvider {

  private static final SessionFactory factory = buildFactory();

  public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return factory;
  }

  private static SessionFactory buildFactory() {
    try {
      Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
      configuration.configure();
      ServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
          configuration.getProperties()).build();
      return configuration.buildSessionFactory(registry);
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
      // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
      System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
      throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

So, now query

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROm pg_stat_activity;
```

returns 6, one of which is psql client. Even after minute of re-requesting page. I think, it's a progress.

The only one thing remains - is to make possible for Hibernate work with postgresql-jdbc.jat in Tomcat /lib folder and no use jar in WEB-INF/lib. I read that placing postgresql-jdbc.jar into WEB-INF/lib may cause memory leaks.

P.S. I also read, that Hibernate should automaticaly close connections when session commits or rollback and I don't need to close connections explicitly.

Thanks for your suggestions, cos I always need someone who keep my eyes open.